# How to import external files in a optimized requirejs project?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, r.js

I am developing a RequireJs project, which one I was able to run R.js on it. I need to exclude a config file from the optimizer and be able to read it from the optimized javascript. I could do the first half of my problem with the following app.build.js:

```
({
    appDir: ".",
    baseUrl: "js",
    mainConfigFile: 'js/main.js',
    paths: {
        requireLib: 'libs/require/require-min',
        jqm: 'libs/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min'
    },
    modules: [
       {
           name: "main",
           include: ["requireLib","jqm"],
           excludeShallow: [
                "config/conf"
           ]
       }
   ],
   optimize: "none"
})
```

What I couldn't achieve is to read config/conf properties from main.js (final js with everything).
Any idea about how I can tackle this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to move the config to the exclude seccion and add config to the path   seccion this way you will build config. something like this:

```
    ({
        appDir: ".",
        baseUrl: "js",
        mainConfigFile: 'js/main.js',
        paths: {
            requireLib: 'libs/require/require-min',
            jqm: 'libs/jqueryMobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min',
            config : 'config/conf'
        },
        modules: [
                  {
                    name: "main",
                    exclude : [
                             'config'
                              ]
                  }
                 ],

       optimize: "none"
    })
```